# Behavior subject has different emit count on value change

Tags: angular, rxjs6

we have one Behavior subject in some service

```js
  city = new BehaviorSubject(config.defaultCity);

  get cityObservable(){
    return this.city.asObservable();
  }
```

when we get the observable in some component we can listen for the value changes so we fetch different data based on city.

like this

```js
  categories: Observable<any>;
  activeCoupons: Observable<any>;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.categories = this.utilsService.cityObservable
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(100),
      switchMap(cityId => this.categoryService.fetchCategories(cityId)),
      map((response: any) => response.data)
    );


    this.activeCoupons = this.utilsService.cityObservable
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(100),
      switchMap(cityId => this.couponService.fetchActiveCoupons(cityId))
    );


  }
```

the problem is that `fetchCategories` get called once when city value change and `fetchActiveCoupons` get called twice when city value change! why did it get its value emitted twice? are not they have the same code?

Answer (score 3):

> the problem is that fetchCategories get called once when city value change and fetchActiveCoupons get called twice when city value change

It gets called twice because it has two subscribers.

You can share the observable and replay the previous value using [shareReplay()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html)

```js
    this.activeCoupons = this.utilsService.cityObservable
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(100),
      switchMap(cityId => this.couponService.fetchActiveCoupons(cityId)),
      shareReplay(1)
    );
```

You can use `shareReplay()` when you have a heavy observable and want to share the results with multiple subscribers, or you want a late subscriber to receive previous values.

Comment: Why convert to `Observable` when you can subscribe directly to the `BehaviourSubject`?

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew Just a stylistic option

Comment: @Reactgular Thank you so much you were right. I've used this Observable twice in the html template `activeCoupons` which means I did subscribe twice and the `shareReplay` did solve the issue elegantly, thank you!

Comment: @LouayAlosh you're welcome. Please accept the answer if it solve your problem.

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew it's an anti pattern to expose subjects outside of a service. It's difficult to track down all of the usages of `next()` if the code passes the subject around. That is the reason the rxjs library has the `asObservable()` method.

Comment: @Rectangular That makes sense. But, instead of passing the subject around, can't it be directly subscribed to? So that the usage of next will only be in the service?